# Excel Conditional Formatting change fill color back to normal after input

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on an Excel sheet for the company that I work for and I am having trouble figuring out a specific task within Conditional Formatting.

So I have a rule:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(B5)=FALSE,IF(COUNTIF('Hidden 
    Sheet'!$C$5:$C$10,"*"&B5&"*")>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

That takes the selection in the drop-down of cell b5 and dictates if this specific cell that I have the conditional format in (N5) should be filled with the color red or not.

That works perfectly fine, but when I type in cell N5 it stays red, when I don't want it to. How can I change the fill back to regular after I input something into the cell?

I can provide additional information upon request.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the CFR formula to,

```
=AND(ISBLANK(N5), NOT(ISBLANK(B5)), COUNTIF('Hidden Sheet'!$C$5:$C$10, "*"&B5&"*")>0)
```